help with bash script to [grep sed cut] smartctl output to desired format
If anyone is good at writing bash scripts, and is inclined to do the following, I am looking to achieve this:
i am horrible at writing bash and more horrible at using cut or sed, and if this can be done with minimal lines in bash I would prefer that than to writing a C program
  smartctl --scan

  /dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
  /dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,3 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_03], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,4 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_04], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,5 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_05], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,6 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_06], SCSI device
  /dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,7 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_07], SCSI device

  # 'sdb' not important just always used 'sda' for the following
  # for m = 0 to n per the --scan output giving 0..7 do
  #   smartctl -a -d megaraid,m /dev/sda | grep/sed/cut XXX
  #   where the XXX results in just   `KPM5WRUG3T84 12345678a` being extracted
  #   from the smartctl -a output being this:
  # end for m

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Product:              KPM5WRUG3T84
User Capacity:        3,840,755,982,336 bytes [3.84 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is resource provisioned, LBPRZ=1
Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Serial number:        12345678a

So for my 8 disks I'm looking to get this formatted output from the script that I can easily open in excel; this is for disk inventory
0 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678a
1 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678b
2 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678c
3 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678d
4 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678d
5 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678e
6 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678f
7 KPM5WRUG3T84  12345678g

update: here is the bash I wrote based off Stephen Kitt's answer below, thanks.
#!/bin/bash

N=`smartctl --scan | grep megaraid | wc -l`

for (( m = 0; m < N; m++ )); do

 echo "$m" $(smartctl -a -d "megaraid,$m" /dev/sda | grep -E '(^Product:|^Serial number:)' | cut -d: -f2)

# this one prints # manuf model serial
# smartctl -a -d "megaraid,$m" /dev/sda -json | jq -r "\"$m \" + .model_name + \" \" + .serial_number"

done


This will extract a single drive’s product name and serial number, in your loop:
(echo "$m"; smartctl -a -d "megaraid,$m" /dev/sda |
 grep -Po '^(Product|Serial number):\s*\K.*') |
paste -s -

This outputs the sequence number, extracts the values in the two relevant lines, and pastes everything into a single line with single space separators.
If your version of smartctl can produce JSON output you might want to parse that with jq instead:
smartctl -a -d "megaraid,$m" /dev/sda -json |
jq -r "\"$m \" + .model_name + \" \" + .serial_number"


First one assumes product and serial don't contain : or glob characters (or backslash depending on shell or version and configuration thereof). May be better as (echo "$m"; smartctl... | grep -Po '^(Product|Serial number):\s*\K.*') | paste -s -

For what you're doing, I think trying to parse the output of smartctl --scan is the wrong solution. If you want a list of model and serial number for all attached drives, you could do something like:
lsblk -nd -o name,model,serial -Q 'TYPE == "disk"' --json |
  jq -r '.blockdevices[]|[values[]|values]|@csv

Which on my system produces:
"sda","Surge","0172000000001537"
"mmcblk0","0xaa675dbe"
"zram0"
"nvme1n1","Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 1TB","S6WSNS0WC09089T"
"nvme0n1","Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 1TB","S6WSNS0WC09099P"

That's ready for importing into your favorite spreadsheet. If it lists devices in which you are not interested, you can just filter those out with grep. E.g:
lsblk -nd -o name,model,serial -Q 'TYPE == "disk"' --json |
  jq -r '.blockdevices[]|[values[]|values]|@csv' |
  grep -Evi 'mmcblk|zram'

Which produces:
"sda","Surge","0172000000001537"
"nvme1n1","Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 1TB","S6WSNS0WC09089T"
"nvme0n1","Samsung SSD 980 PRO with Heatsink 1TB","S6WSNS0WC09099P"


your lsblk on my system with  a raid card results with sda    PERC H740P Adp   00edc23529854d432d006bbd48f0a7ce and similiar for sdb and that's it.  If I wasn't using a raid card and I had 8 SATA ports then I think this would work

Got it, thanks for the comment.

Here's an extensible awk solution:
# For each MegaRAID device...
for m in $(smartctl --scan | grep megaraid | cut -d, -f2)
do
    # Scan it and report the index, product, and serial number
    smartctl -a -d megaraid,"$m" /dev/sda |
        awk -F': *' -v i="$i" '
            $1=="Product" { p=$2 }
            $1=="Serial number" { printf "%1d %s\t%s\n", i, p, $2; p="" }
        '
done

